# Concurrency: how to implement an executor with both incoming and outgoing queues?

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, producer-consumer

As we know, ThreadPoolExecutor uses some BlockingQueue as a queue of incoming tasks. What I want is to have ThreadPoolExecutor that has a *second* queue for the task results which are ready. I want to use this queue as a source for input/output services which send or store these results.

Why I want to create a separate queue? Because I want to decouple action of sending results from action of obtaining results. Also, I suppose any Exceptions and Delays that accompany input/output operations should not affect my ThreadPoolExecutor which is calculating the result.

I have created some naive implementation of this. I would like to get some criticism on this. May be, it can be implemented with out-of-the-box Java classes better? I use Java 7.

```
public class ThreadPoolWithResultQueue {
    interface Callback<T> {
        void complete(T t);
    }
    public abstract static class CallbackTask<T> implements Runnable {
        private final Callback callback;   
        CallbackTask(Callback callback) {
            this.callback = callback;
        }    
        public abstract T execute();   
        final public void run() {
            T t = execute();
            callback.complete(t);
        }
    }   
    public static class CallBackTaskString extends CallbackTask<String> {
        public CallBackTaskString(Callback callback) {
            super(callback);
        }
        @Override
        public String execute() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            return hashCode() + "-" + System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
        final BlockingQueue<String> resultQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
        Callback<String> addToQueueCallback = new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void complete(String s) {
                System.out.println("Adding Result To Queue " + s);
                resultQueue.add(s); //adding to outgoing queue. some other executor (or same one?) will process it
            }
        };
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(3, 5, 1000l, TimeUnit.DAYS, workQueue);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            executor.submit(new CallBackTaskString(addToQueueCallback));
        };
        System.out.println("All submitted.");
        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(10l, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("Result queue size " + resultQueue.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you put all that extra `Callback` in there so the code seems more clever, or do you need/want to do it that way? A straightforward implementation just involves one more queue, and if you know how to put things in queues it should be obvious.

Comment: One word: `ExecutorCompletionService`.

Comment: Kayaman, yes its simplier to add results to outgoing queue right in the Runnable to execute. But I try to decouple as much as possible. Anyway, Marko suggested a great thing.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of makinf a library component, you would have to wrap things up...

You could extend The thread pool executor which has a number of methods to intercept the submitted tasks, so you would queue thing out to a queue passed in the constructor.

That's basically ExecutorCompletionService, but you would allow the user to plug a queue instead of appearing as one.

Otherwise, this is typical proxying of the task. Fair job.